# How to create a new column in Python, based on an existing column

Tags: python, pandas

Response:

[image: Response]

I need to create a 'Response' column based on an existing 'Time' column. My response variable has to display 'No' for Time values from 1s to 60s and from 240s to 300s. And display "Yes' for all the remaining values.

I tried the code below but it simply displays 'No' for all the 'Time' values, disregarding the given condition.

Dataset:

[image: Dataset]

```
dataset['Y'] = np.where(dataset["Time"] > 60 & (dataset["Time"] < 240 ), 'yes', 'no')
```

Comment: You need another set of parenthesis around dataset["Time"] > 60, otherwise it works like dataset["Time"] > 60 &True -> which is always False

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def label(row):
    if row['Time'] >= 1 and row['Time'] < 60:
        return("no")
    elif row['Time'] >= 240 and row['Time'] < 300:
        return("no")
    else:
        return("yes")

dataset['Y'] = dataset.apply(lambda row: label(row), axis=1)
```

In your code, your condition is wrong so it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to do the following:

```
dataset['Y'] = (dataset['Time'] >= 1) & (dataset['Time'] <= 4) | (dataset['Time'] > 5)
```

Note that this will fill your 'Y' column with bool values. If it's paramount that they are Yes/No then you can add change it to

```
dataset['Y'] = ((dataset['Time'] >= 1) & (dataset['Time'] <= 4) | (dataset['Time'] > 5)).replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```

Also note that rather than convert your time column into seconds I converted your time intervals into minutes, however you may want to do this different for readability.